Tailscale Funnel and Websockets
I have a Flask App running inside a docker container. A user uploads a file via the web interface and the app starts to process the file. It sends the user messages via a websocket connection.
This works fine inside the Tailscale VPN. When exposed to the internet via Funnel, the websockets never make it to the webpage. See error message below from the Flask App. Turbo is the library I use.
Should I be opening a new Funnel for websockets and should that be HTTPS and/or HTTP?
[2024-07-18 13:18:03,323] ERROR in app: Exception on /processUpload [POST]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

  File "/opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

  File "/opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

  File "/opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request

    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]

  File "/home/app.py", line 103, in processUpload

    turbo.push(turbo.update(render_template('_svgStats.html'), 'uploadResultsText'), to=user.id)

  File "/opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.10/site-packages/turbo_flask/turbo.py", line 198, in push

    for ws in self.clients[recipient]:

KeyError: UUID('46868fc3-d6e8-457f-b65a-30649f57c494')

